# awk script to rearrange similar rows

Tags: bash, awk, perl

I want rearrange about 5 million rows (with 300 columns) into groups.

Data looks like the following: where there were various experiments (column 2) conducted at different locations (column headers in top row column 4 onwards) in different years (column 1) using instruments (column 3). The numbers in the matrix ( row 2 onwards, column 4 onwards) indicate how many instances of experiments were successful.

What I want is to rearrange the rows

Input

```
                        345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352
2014    Exp1    IBM         24          45  22      
2014    Exp2    LEN     23      32  34              
2014    Exp3    LEN     2       34  34              
2014    Exp4    IBM         34          44  43      
2014    Exp5    IBM         2   45      51  45      
2014    Exp6    IBM             34      23  54      
2014    Exp7    IBM         23          23  24      
2014    Exp8    IBM             34      45  56      
2014    Exp9    LEN     24      45  45              
2014    Exp10   LEN     43      45  32              
2015    Exp11   IBM         34          55  33      34
2015    Exp12   IBM     1       33          4       5
2015    Exp13   IBM         43          55  34      43
2015    Exp14   IBM         45          32  43      4
2015    Exp15   IBM             23          4       5
2015    Exp16   IBM     32  34      43              
2015    Exp17   IBM     32  34      46              
2015    Exp18   LEN             32      54      67  
2015    Exp19   SCL         56  6       4   45      56
2015    Exp20   LEN             67      56      76  
2015    Exp21   LEN             45      56      65  
2015    Exp22   SCL         45              55      54
2015    Exp23   SCL         4               55      45
```

What I would like to have are the rows rearranged into groups such that

1) Within the same year
2) Using the same instrument

create groups such that,

each group has at least 3 locations in common, each of which has at least 20 successful experiments.

Requested Output

```
                        345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352
1   2014    Exp1    IBM     24          45  22      
1   2014    Exp4    IBM     34          44  43      
1   2014    Exp7    IBM     23          23  24      
2   2014    Exp2    LEN 23      32  34              
2   2014    Exp9    LEN 24      45  45              
2   2014    Exp10   LEN 43      45  32              
3   2014    Exp5    IBM     2   45      51  45      
3   2014    Exp6    IBM         34      23  54      
3   2014    Exp8    IBM         34      45  56      
4   2015    Exp11   IBM     34          55  33      34
4   2015    Exp13   IBM     43          55  34      43
4   2015    Exp14   IBM     45          32  43      4
5   2015    Exp16   IBM 32  34      43              
5   2015    Exp17   IBM 32  34      46              
6   2015    Exp18   LEN         32      54      67  
6   2015    Exp20   LEN         67      56      76  
6   2015    Exp21   LEN         45      56      65  
7   2015    Exp19   SCL     56  6       4   45      56
7   2015    Exp22   SCL     45              55      54
    2014    Exp3    LEN 2       34  34              
    2015    Exp12   IBM 1       33          4       5
    2015    Exp15   IBM         23          4       5
    2015    Exp23   SCL     4               55      45
```

Here is what I tried.

```
awk ' NR>1{ for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!="") arr1[$1,$2,$3]=$i ; next } 
    $1,$2,$3 in arr1 { 
        for (j=1;j<length(arr1);j++)) 
            {if (arr1[j] > 20)
            group++;
 END {
   for (j in n) {
      print group, arr1[j]
   }
}' input input
```

Comment: As far as I can see, to group the output correctly would require some form of clustering. This is non-trivial, and there would be several "correct" solutions in terms of how the rows were ordered.

Answer (score 1):

A few random hints depending on the actual data formatting and other issues...

How are the data fields separated? (The first three spacings give the impression that there's a TAB character in between, while the last columns seem space separated.) You should be aware that the column information is lost for the culumns 4-N if your field separator is defined as per default. So the logic of your code is seriously flawed.

If you have **no** TAB separators but all blanks you can use GNU `awk`'s `FIELDWIDTHS` feature to access the data (including the missing "blank" data, as you seem to be trying to achieve).

If you have TABs for the first three separators and blanks for the rest you should explocitly define `FS="\t"`, so that you can directly work on fields 1-3 and have the spacing intact in the final data (that you can address as a whole as field 4), which will make it easy to find "blank data".

It may further make processing easier if you create subsets of your data on the fly, operate on those, and concatenate the individual subsets afterwards. To separate the data in files depening on, say, *year* and *instrument* you can write:

```
awk '{ print > "set_" $1 "_" $3" }' input
```

and it will create files named, e.g., `set_2015_LEN` or `set_2014_IBM` containing the respective entries.

The final task to identify "matching numeric column sets" depends on the previously mentioned topics; if, for example, the final eigth data columns can be addressed as one fixed length entity it might suffice to use the `sort` utility with an appropriately defined key-specification (see `sort`'s option `-k`).

(BTW: for a compound index test instead of `$1,$2,$3 in arr1` you have to write `($1,$2,$3) in arr1`.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, the data is tab delimited, I couldnt seem to line it up in this post, so introduced some manual spaces...the actual data has 300 columns, what I am thinking is replacing the >20 values by 1 and the others by blank, so that I can treat it as a fixed length entity. I checked out the sort -k option, but I couldn't follow how that would apply here specially for so many columns, would you give me a small example? thanks again for your suggestion on splitting the data-set.